# Uploading file to amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am working with a javafx project with google auth2.0 for sign in and amazon s3 for storing files. I wrote the following code for this purpose. I have a file chooser for uploading image to s3. The app works well with sign in but when I try to upload files to s3 it gives some exception which is given below.

main.java

```
package main;
import controller.signupController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage signinStage,signupStage,mainSatge,decreptStage,profilestage,aws;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/signinScreen.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
        Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style/styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void mainWindow(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/mainScreen.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
            mainSatge=new Stage();
            mainSatge.setScene(scene);scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style/styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());
            mainSatge.setScene(scene);
            mainSatge.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));
            mainSatge.setResizable(false);
            mainSatge.show();
        }catch (Exception c){

        }
    }

    public void signupWindow(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/signupScreen.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(pane);

            signupController controller=loader.getController();
            controller.main(this, signupStage);

            signupStage=new Stage();
            signupStage.setScene(scene);scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style/styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());
            signupStage.setScene(scene);
            signupStage.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));

            signupStage.setResizable(true);
            signupStage.show();
        }catch (Exception c){

        }

    }


    public void decreptWindow(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/decreptImageScreen.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
            decreptStage=new Stage();
            decreptStage.setScene(scene);scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/style/styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());
            decreptStage.setScene(scene);
            decreptStage.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));
            decreptStage.setResizable(true);
            decreptStage.show();
        }catch (Exception c){

        }

    }

    public void profilewindow(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/profile.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
            profilestage=new Stage();
            profilestage.setScene(scene);
            profilestage.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));
            profilestage.setResizable(false);
            profilestage.show();
        }catch (Exception c){

        }

    }

    public void aws(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/aws.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane=loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(pane);
            aws=new Stage();
            aws.setScene(scene);
            aws.getIcons().addAll(new Image("/src/Cornie-icons-00.png"));
            aws.setResizable(false);
            aws.show();
        }catch (Exception c){

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

mainController.java

```
package controller;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import entity.imageEntity;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import main.Main;
import org.kairos.components.RippleViewRow;
import org.kairos.layouts.RecyclerView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class mainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXButton historyBTN;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton addBTN;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton DecryptimageBTN,logoutBTN;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton contactsBTN;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton profileBTN;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton aboutBTN;

    @FXML
    private Label nameLB;

    @FXML
    private Label loggedInEmail;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageProfile;

    @FXML
    private Label usernameLB;
    @FXML
    private RecyclerView<imageEntity> recycleView;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane blackPane;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane drawerPane;

    @FXML
    private Label imageLink;

    @FXML
    private ImageView drawerIcon;

    boolean drawer_show=true;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageUpload;

    @FXML
    private ImageView img;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        loggedInEmail.setText(Web.getLoggedIn().getDisplayName());
        imageLink.setText(Web.getLoggedIn().getBirthday());
        usernameLB.setText(Web.getLoggedIn().getGender()); 
        imageProfile.setImage(new Image(Web.getLoggedIn().getImage().getUrl()));
        imageProfile.setClip(new Circle(100));

        blackPane.setVisible(false);
        FadeTransition fadeTransition=new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1),blackPane);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(1);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0);
        fadeTransition.play();

        TranslateTransition translateTransition=new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1),drawerPane);
        translateTransition.setToX(-500);
        translateTransition.play();

        drawerIcon.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (drawer_show==true){
                blackPane.setVisible(true);

                FadeTransition fadeTransition1=new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1),blackPane);
                fadeTransition1.setFromValue(0);
                fadeTransition1.setToValue(0.12);
                fadeTransition1.play();

                TranslateTransition translateTransition1=new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1),drawerPane);
                translateTransition1.setToX(0);
                translateTransition1.play();
                drawer_show=false;
                drawerIcon.setImage(new Image("/src/left_arrow.png"));
                }else {
                FadeTransition fadeTransition0=new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1),blackPane);
                fadeTransition0.setFromValue(0.12);
                fadeTransition0.setToValue(0);
                fadeTransition0.play();
                fadeTransition0.setOnFinished(event1 -> {
                        blackPane.setVisible(false);
                        });
                TranslateTransition translateTransition0=new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1),drawerPane);
                translateTransition0.setToX(-500);
                translateTransition0.play();
                drawerIcon.setImage(new Image("/src/drawer.png"));
                drawer_show=true;

                }
        });

        blackPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                FadeTransition fadeTransition0=new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1),blackPane);
                fadeTransition0.setFromValue(0.12);
                fadeTransition0.setToValue(0);
                fadeTransition0.play();
                fadeTransition0.setOnFinished(event1 -> {
                        blackPane.setVisible(false);
                        });
                TranslateTransition translateTransition0=new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1),drawerPane);
                translateTransition0.setToX(-500);
                translateTransition0.play();
                drawerIcon.setImage(new Image("/src/drawer.png"));
                drawer_show=true;
                });

        profileBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_account_circle_black_24dp.png")));
        historyBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_assignment_black_24dp.png")));
        contactsBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_contacts_black_24dp.png")));
        aboutBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_error_outline_black_24dp.png")));
        DecryptimageBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_error_outline_black_24dp.png")));
        logoutBTN.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/src/ic_power_settings_new_black_24dp.png")));

        DecryptimageBTN.setOnAction(event -> {
                new Main().decreptWindow();
                });

        profileBTN.setOnAction(event -> {
                new Main().profilewindow();
                });

        contactsBTN.setOnAction(event -> {
                new Main().aws();
                });

        Adapter adapter=new Adapter();

        imageEntity imageEntity=new imageEntity();
        imageEntity.setImageSrc("/src/preview_tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege-ubisoft-montreal2.jpg");
        imageEntity.setName("Image Name: Test Image");
        imageEntity.setDate("Date Uploaded: 23-04-2017");
        imageEntity.setPrice("Price: $3.5");

        recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recycleView.getItems().addAll(imageEntity,imageEntity,imageEntity,imageEntity,imageEntity);

        addBTN.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                FileChooser fileChooser=new FileChooser();
                fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("c:\\"));
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG Images","*.jpg"),
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPEG Images","*.jpeg"),
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG Images","*.png"));
                File file=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                if (file!=null){
                AWSCredentials Credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                        "client key",
                        "client secret");
                AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Credentials);
                String bucketName = "awsimagetrading";
                String key = file.getName();
                System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
                AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(Credentials);
                s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,key,file));
                URL url = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(bucketName,key,Date.from(Instant.now().plus(5,ChronoUnit.MINUTES)));
                System.out.println(url);
                //img.setImage(new Image( file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()));

                }
                }
        });
    }


    public  class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder> {

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewRow call(ListView listView) {
            return new RippleViewRow(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Holder onCreateViewHolder(FXMLLoader fxmlLoader) {
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(mainController.class.getResource("/view/imageCardViewScreen.fxml"));
            Holder holder = new Holder(fxmlLoader);
            return holder;
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, Object o) {

            imageEntity imageEntity = (imageEntity) o;
            holder.imageView.setImage(new Image(imageEntity.getImageSrc()));
            holder.name.setText(imageEntity.getName());
            holder.price.setText(imageEntity.getPrice());
            holder.date.setText(imageEntity.getDate());

        }

        public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            @FXML
            private Label date;

            @FXML
            private JFXButton download;

            @FXML
            private Label price;

            @FXML
            private Label name;

            @FXML
            private ImageView imageView;

            public Holder(FXMLLoader loader) {
                super(loader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/util/Args
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Scheme.java:91)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:50)
at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createPoolingClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:29)
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:97)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:164)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:119)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:103)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:357)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:339)
at controller.AWSUpoladController$1.handle(AWSUpoladController.java:64)
at controller.AWSUpoladController$1.handle(AWSUpoladController.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

When I use the amazon s3 separately it works fine but it's not working when I try to integrate it with my app. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with library. Just use the appropriate library version and that will solve it.